# How explicitly specify response language?

Tags: http, header, request, locale

### Why does [google.com](http://google.com) ignore explicitly specified Accept-Language?

I am in Germany, and interface of [google.com](http://google.com) is in german. But my idea - set language so that interface become english, for example.

I have tried to create request using Postman and REST Easy and set Accept-Language to "en-US, en", but both return me interface in german.

I guess, that my location also influences response language.

I also tried to adjust about:config intl.accept_languages entry in Firefox to get other response language, but that also didn't help.

Is it possible to get another interface language without hiding my location?

The only thing that changes - google adds a link in the bottom of page that allows to change UI to english.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem consisted from parts:

1. inappropriate tool for requesting, that showed me mangled
   results;
2. Google has its own rules how to form response. For
   English language only link to english interface is inserted into
   page. For languages which are very different, the interface is
   returned in requested language at once.

C u.